# Odd query appended to url when logging in with Laravel9 (jetstream)

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

I have a Laravel9 app, working pretty well but I have a weird issue with url's when I log in. So after logging in I expect my url suffix to be `/dashboard` but instead i get a query string appended like this `/dashboard?%2Fdashboard=` It doesn't break anything but is not expected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

because it is a **get** route and form

so the query parameters should be resubmit by a second button on the form which would have the new URL

so if you want to show the parameters in URL replace type of method to something like `POST`

hopefully that is help you

Comment: but this is the dashboard page which is a get in my routes file. It is so far as I can tell default behaviour i.e. i have been logged out through inactivity, when i log back in i get redirected to the last page i was on prior to being logged out and this has the string attached. the dashboard page is the generic default dashboard that comes with jetstream.